# Left join running much faster than inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying to optimise the performance of a query which I've managed to do massively. It's gone from 36.7 seconds to 3.3 seconds using a left join but I don't quite understand why the left join is giving me such a jump in performance compared to a normal join.

The result set bought back by both queries are identical.

Here are the queries with the EXPLAIN...

**Normal join: 36.7 seconds**

```
SELECT t1.entityId, SUM(t2.gbp) AS amount
FROM transactionsV2 t1
JOIN
(
    SELECT
    t.uniqueId,
    ROUND((CASE WHEN t.currency != "GBP" THEN t.amount/er.exchange_rate ELSE t.amount END), 2) AS gbp
    FROM transactionsV2 t
    JOIN total_control.exchange_rates er 
    ON t.currency = er.currency
    ) t2
ON t1.uniqueId = t2.uniqueId
WHERE t1.paymentType IN ("DB", "3D")
AND t1.processing_time >= '2019-04-01 00:00:00'
AND t1.processing_time <= '2019-04-20 23:59:59'
AND t1.status = 1
GROUP BY t1.entityId
```

[image]

**Left join: 3.3 seconds**

```
SELECT t1.entityId, SUM(t2.gbp) AS amount
FROM transactionsV2 t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
    t.uniqueId,
    ROUND((CASE WHEN t.currency != "GBP" THEN t.amount/er.exchange_rate ELSE t.amount END), 2) AS gbp
    FROM transactionsV2 t
    JOIN total_control.exchange_rates er 
    ON t.currency = er.currency
    ) t2
ON t1.uniqueId = t2.uniqueId
WHERE t1.paymentType IN ("DB", "3D")
AND t1.processing_time >= '2019-04-01 00:00:00'
AND t1.processing_time <= '2019-04-20 23:59:59'
AND t1.status = 1
GROUP BY t1.entityId
```

[image]

Comment: you executed the two query one after another?  ... try invert the sequence  ..

Comment: I've tried that but still the same result. I've also ran the queries in separate browsers so don't think it's anything to do with caching.

Comment: Still the same @RaymondNijland. It's not a caching issue.

Comment: Well without knowing table structure and indexes we are not going to solve this one thats for sure i've tryed with a logical answer.. You should edit the question without the output off `SHOW CREATE TABLE transactionsV2`

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help -- as would a description of what the query is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you express this as a correlated subquery?

```
SELECT t.entityId,
       (SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN t2.currency <> 'GBP' THEN t2.amount/er.exchange_rate ELSE t.amount END)j
SUM(t2.gbp) AS amount
        FROM transactionsV2 t2 JOIN
             total_control.exchange_rates er 
             ON t.currency = er.currency
        WHERE t2.uniqueid = t.uniqueid
FROM transactionsV2 t
WHERE t.paymentType IN ('DB', '3D') AND
      t.processing_time >= '2019-04-01' AND
      t.processing_time < '2019-04-21' AND
      t.status = 1;
```

If so, you may be able to add indexes to the underlying tables to improve performance.  However, I suspect that the transactions table is really a view.

Answer (score 0):

Although I can not explain why it is doing what it is doing... I dont know why you are self-joining when all transactions are originating from the TransactionsV2 table.  The inner left-join is pulling ALL transactions joined to an exchange rate but has no where applied thus pulling all transactions.  THEN joining to the outer instance for specific date.

From what I am seeing, your TransactionV2 table has a structure something like...

```
UniqueID auto-increment
EntityID (such as multiple transactions for this one person/company/entity)
Amount (based on relation to exchange rate and transaction amount)
```

So you are taking every unique ID in the outer to the unique ID on the inner
once the exchange rate computation is done, but still ultimately grouping by entity...
I would try something like.

```
SELECT
        t1.EntityID,
        SUM( ROUND(CASE WHEN t1.currency != "GBP" 
                        THEN t.amount/er.exchange_rate 
                        ELSE t.amount END, 2) ) Amount
    from
        TransactionsV2 t1
            LEFT JOIN total_control.exchange_rates er 
                ON t1.currency = er.currency
    WHERE 
            t1.paymentType IN ("DB", "3D")
        AND t1.processing_time >= '2019-04-01 00:00:00'
        AND t1.processing_time <= '2019-04-20 23:59:59'
        AND t1.status = 1
    GROUP BY 
        t1.entityId
```

It's going through the records ONCE and only for the criteria.  I changed the join to exchange rates to a LEFT-JOIN in case no record -- as I don't know the exact conditions that may (or not) have a match.. Maybe that's your != "GBP" value in the case/when.

To help ensure some optimization, and amount of transactions, I would build a compound index on your transaction table on

```
( Status, Processing_Time, PaymentType, EntityID )
```

Comment: Hi @DRapp, your query executes slightly faster than mine, 3.1 seconds as opposed to 3.3 so that's great. Looking at my query, you're completely right. The self-join is completely unnecessary. The thing that I still don't understand is that with the left-join to the exchange_rates table, the query executes in 3.1 seconds but with an inner join, it takes 12 seconds yet the result-set is identical. Why is there such a performance hit when using an inner-join as opposed to left?

Comment: @Dally, Sorry, can't answer why the speed difference, but FYI, I found that MySQL has a keyword "STRAIGHT_JOIN" which tells engine run in the order I give it to you.  I had one query fail out after 24hrs with parent table and 20+ child lookup tables.  Added straight_join and the query finished less than 2 hrs.  Data was more than 23 million rows.  Who knows, but may help you some day too.

Answer (score 0):

I guess performance is different because of different ways of tables join which is used by `INNER JOIN (JOIN)` and `LEFT JOIN` and their influence on indexes.

For first look at the order in `EXPLAIN`.
You can see that `LEFT JOIN` will join tables in fixed order (left to right). 
`INNER JOIN` - the optimizer will build join order for you (small table first).
For both cases `key` for table `t1` (in `EXPLAIN` list) is different.

It always depends on the structure of your tables would be index (correct index) applied or not when is different join order. It can depend even, for example, on a different table collations.

Look at this way, I hope it will have result.

Comment: Is it safe to say that in most instances, a left join will outperform an inner join? I know the 2 different joins do different things and yield different results but if you know what you're doing, you can yield the same results from an inner and a left join but will the left always be faster?

Comment: No, in theory INNER JOIN is faster. 
It depends on your task... It's different JOINs for different things. You should choose the best one which is is suitable for your task and yield result with hight performance.

Comment: In my instance I thought an inner join would’ve been more appropriate but it’s obviously not performance wise.